# Export multiples files in an output directory while renaming them as months

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, rename, mean

I have various .tif files (3 files per month) from 2006-2010. Nomenclature of files are as following:

```
20060103
20060113
20060124
20060203
20060213
20060221
...
...
...
20100624
```

I have calculated monthly mean spatial plots of the files using the code given below: (with raster, rgdal and sp packages)

```
rast <- list.files(path="D:/Test",pattern='.*tif',full.names=TRUE)
s <- stack(rast)
grp <- rep(1:5, rep(3,5))
grp
ab_mean <- stackApply(s, grp, mean)
plot(ab_mean)
```

I want to export the monthly mean spatial rasters to an output directory and at the same time, I want to rename the raster files in a way that the output file should take the month and year from the input files (such as 01/2006 or Jan 2006...) to avoid any confusion in case of missing data.

I know month.name function but it is not serving the purpose.

I am coding in R.

Comment: Do you have 36 files for the first four years and then some more for the first six months of 2010? That should be 162 files. Your `grp` vector is horribly short in that case. I'm guessing this is maybe a test folder with fewer files in it? Better to get the grouping from the file name than constructing a vector like this.

Comment: Yes, the code I mentioned in the question is for a test folder with few files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a folder with 162 tiffs in it that should roughly replicate your data. Here's the first 10:

```
> rast <- list.files(path="./data/",pattern='.*tif',full.names=TRUE)
> rast[1:10]
 [1] "./data//20060103.tif" "./data//20060113.tif" "./data//20060121.tif"
 [4] "./data//20060203.tif" "./data//20060213.tif" "./data//20060221.tif"
 [7] "./data//20060303.tif" "./data//20060313.tif" "./data//20060321.tif"
[10] "./data//20060403.tif"
```

When I make the stack, I get the year-month-date from the filename in the names:

```
> s <- stack(rast)
> names(s)[1:10]
 [1] "X20060103" "X20060113" "X20060121" "X20060203" "X20060213" "X20060221"
 [7] "X20060303" "X20060313" "X20060321" "X20060403"
```

with an X to make it non-numeric. Now my grouping is going to be based on the year-month, which is the first 7 characters of the name (including the X, we'll keep that):

```
> grp = substr(names(s),1,7)
> grp[1:10]
 [1] "X200601" "X200601" "X200601" "X200602" "X200602" "X200602" "X200603"
 [8] "X200603" "X200603" "X200604"
```

Now apply means over the groupings in the stack. The resulting stack has useful names:

```
> ab_mean <- stackApply(s, grp, mean)
> names(ab_mean)[1:10]
 [1] "index_X200601" "index_X200602" "index_X200603" "index_X200604"
 [5] "index_X200605" "index_X200606" "index_X200607" "index_X200608"
 [9] "index_X200609" "index_X200610"
```

So we can loop over the names, extract the layer, and write it using the name:

```
> for(n in names(ab_mean)){writeRaster(ab_mean[[n]], paste0(n,".tif"))}
>
```

and that gives me 54 individual single-layer TIFF files output:

```
> list.files(path=".",pattern=".tif")
 [1] "index_X200601.tif" "index_X200602.tif" "index_X200603.tif"
 [4] "index_X200604.tif" "index_X200605.tif" "index_X200606.tif"
 [7] "index_X200607.tif" "index_X200608.tif" "index_X200609.tif"
[10] "index_X200610.tif" "index_X200611.tif" "index_X200612.tif"
[13] "index_X200701.tif" "index_X200702.tif" "index_X200703.tif"
[16] "index_X200704.tif" "index_X200705.tif" "index_X200706.tif"
[19] "index_X200707.tif" "index_X200708.tif" "index_X200709.tif"
[22] "index_X200710.tif" "index_X200711.tif" "index_X200712.tif"
[25] "index_X200801.tif" "index_X200802.tif" "index_X200803.tif"
[28] "index_X200804.tif" "index_X200805.tif" "index_X200806.tif"
[31] "index_X200807.tif" "index_X200808.tif" "index_X200809.tif"
[34] "index_X200810.tif" "index_X200811.tif" "index_X200812.tif"
[37] "index_X200901.tif" "index_X200902.tif" "index_X200903.tif"
[40] "index_X200904.tif" "index_X200905.tif" "index_X200906.tif"
[43] "index_X200907.tif" "index_X200908.tif" "index_X200909.tif"
[46] "index_X200910.tif" "index_X200911.tif" "index_X200912.tif"
[49] "index_X201001.tif" "index_X201002.tif" "index_X201003.tif"
[52] "index_X201004.tif" "index_X201005.tif" "index_X201006.tif"
```

Use whatever string processing you want to create according to whatever naming convention you want to use.

Also, try and use the `terra` package.

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using a dates object and not a brute-force index. This goes to repeatability of your code on additional data. Say, if you were to use this code with data that had a different measurement interval your "grp" index would be irrelevant. You can mitigate this by creating a dates object then indexing the year, month to derive mean and write results with the relevant names. Once again, using terra. The raster package will be depreciated and removed from CRAN in October, as will sp and rgdal (which, in fact, you are not using in your example).

First, create a dates vector from your format and a dummy raster stack.

```
library(terra)

( dates <- seq(as.Date("20000101", "%Y%m%d"), 
               as.Date("20051230", "%Y%m%d"), 
               "weeks") )

s <- rast(nrows=100, ncols=100, nlyrs=length(months))
  s <- rast(lapply(1:nlyr(s), function(i) {
         mm <- c(sample(1:50,1), sample(51:100,1))   
         s[[i]] <- setValues(s[[i]], runif(size(s[[i]]), mm[1], mm[2] )) 
       }))
```

Now, we can set up an iterator by pulling unique months and years and combining them into a set of unique combinations using `expand.grid`. The we can use a for loop to index the correct rasters in the stack, calculate mean and write the output following a "yyyy_mm.tif" format.

```
months <-  format(dates, "%m")
years <- format(dates, "%Y")
ym <- expand.grid(unique(years), unique(months), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  for( i in 1:nrow(ym) ) {
    ij = as.character(ym[i,])
    n = paste0(paste(ij[1],ij[2],sep="_"),".tif")
    idx <- which(years %in% ij[1]) 
    midx <- idx[which(months[idx] %in% ij[2])]
    r <- mean(s[[midx]], na.rm=TRUE)
      writeRaster(r, n)       
  }
```

You can understand the code by defining the iterator and stepping through.

```
i = 35 
( ij = as.character(ym[i,]) )
```

Which results in 2004 and 06. We then use the year, month to create the output name and create an index of the dates that represents the given subset.

```
( n = paste0(paste(ij[1],ij[2],sep="_"),".tif") ) )
( idx <- which(years %in% ij[1]) )
( midx <- idx[which(months[idx] %in% ij[2])] )
```

This index can then be used directly on the raster layers to index the associate year, month and calculate the mean.

```
s[[midx]]
r <- mean(s[[midx]], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with `terra::tapp` like this

```
library(terra)
ff <- list.files(path="D:/Test",pattern='.*tif',full.names=TRUE)
s <- rast(ff)
d <- gsub(".tif", "", basename(ff))
d <- as.Date(d, "%Y%m%d")
time(s) <- d
x <- tapp(s, "yearmonths", mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

With some example data

```
s <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, nlyr=365, vals=1:36500)
time(s) <- as.Date("2000-12-31") + 1:365
x <- tapp(s, "yearmonths", mean, na.rm=TRUE)

x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 12  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source(s)   : memory
#names       : ym_200101, ym_200102, ym_200103, ym_200104, ym_200105, ym_200106, ... 
#min values  :      1501,      4451,      7401,     10451,     13501,     16551, ... 
#max values  :      1600,      4550,      7500,     10550,     13600,     16650, ... 
#time (ymnts): 2001-Jan to 2001-Dec
```

You could add "filename='out.tif'" to `tapp` to write to a single file. If you really want to write each layer as separate files, you can do

```
y <- writeRaster(x, filename=paste0(names(x), ".tiff"))
```